# Bootstrap dropwndown menu with reponsive layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a website and I'm having a problem with a bootstrap class. The class dropdown is working fine when the page is fully opened, but when it goes to the collapse mode, the list of the dropdown menu is still open. What should I do to keep this closed until someone clicks on it? Here goes the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CEDEME</title>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="brand">CEDEME</a>
                <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Pedido de Animais<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Consultar</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Incluir</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Extratos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Cadastro de Alunos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Previsão de Animais</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you are using the Bootstrap 2 code. You tagged this question Bootstrap 3, so assuming you are using the v3 CSS, that would be the main source of your problem.

I would check out the [Bootstrap 3 docs on navbars](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) to get the correct HTML structure.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry about the tag, i don't know how to remove it... By the way, i've already try to read a lot of things, and Bootstrap 3 docs was one of them. I don't know a lot about html and php, and I'm having these problems.

Answer (score 0):

try putting class name "collapse" beside the "nav-collapse". try if that works :)

And also, if your using bootstrap 2, you dont need the bootstrap-responsive.js anymore.. bootstrap.min.js is enough. And I think its better to put all your javascript file below, just before the closing body tag. Hope that helps :)

Comment: I don't know what is the bootstrap I'm using, but i need the "bootstrap-responsive.js" to the "dropdown" works. And put the "collapse" beside the "nav-collapse" didn't work.

Comment: well if you just downloaded bootstrap recently most probably its version 2. With version 2, bootstrap-responsive.js is not even included when you download it.